# What does the brake adjuster nut do? Sturmey Archer S2C coaster brake hub

Tags: hub, coaster

Looking at the [schematics](http://www.sturmey-archer.com/files/catalog/files/291/PART%20LIST%20-%20S2C.pdf) of the sturmey archer S2C hub I noticed this part:

```
2     HMN425    Brake Adjuster Nut (Xylan)
```

And I was wondering, what does it exactly adjust? Does it adjust the brake power? Or just the position of the brake arm? Or something else brake related?

Comment: You screw it in until the brakes are tight, then back it off a little.

Comment: So you are saying it's not adjusting, it's more like securing/holding the brake parts?
How do you know the brakes are tight? Or do you mean 'until te nut is tight' ?

Comment: If the nut's too tight the brakes wheel won't turn.  You want it loose enough that the brakes don''t drag, but tight enough that the brakes work when activated.  I learned this when I was about 12.

Comment: @DanielRHicks is it a bit like the adjuster barrel on road dual pivot brakes, then?

Comment: @WeiwenNg - A little bit.  But the hub brake adjustment is far less fussy.